# Can someone calling function errors?

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a program on how to simulate a car for school. I have the majority of the program done however, I'm stumped on an error. 
I called these functions mid program:

```
find_gallons(total_distance, mpg)

find_total_cost (gallon, cost_per_gallon)

def find_gallons(total_distance, mpg):

    try:
       gallon = total_distance / mpg 
       print(gallon)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("MPG is Zero!")

    return gallon

def find_total_cost(gallon, cost_per_gallon):

    total_cost = gallon * cost_per_gallon 

    return total_cost
```

The error is saying that find_gallons and find_total_cost are not defined.

Comment: where are you calling the functions? and this is all within the class correct? Also, double check your indentation

Comment: I agree that indentation could be the problem. Can you edit your question so that all the code is in one code block and we can see it as a unit, rather than some that looks like code and some that looks like just text? It would help others help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `find_gallons(total_distance, mpg)` and the other function before defining them.

```
def find_gallons(total_distance, mpg):

    try:
       gallon = total_distance / mpg 
       print(gallon)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("MPG is Zero!")

    return gallon

def find_total_cost(gallon, cost_per_gallon):

    total_cost = gallon * cost_per_gallon 

    return total_cost

find_gallons(total_distance, mpg)
find_total_cost (gallon, cost_per_gallon) # Now calling after defining.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code formatting isn't completely clear, but you can't call a function in python before you've defined it. Move the calls below the definition.

```
def find_gallons(total_distance, mpg):
try:
   gallon = total_distance / mpg 
   print(gallon)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("MPG is Zero!")

return gallon
def find_total_cost(gallon, cost_per_gallon):

total_cost = gallon * cost_per_gallon 

return total_cost

find_gallons(total_distance, mpg)

find_total_cost (gallon, cost_per_gallon)
```

Comment: ok i moved the calls below the definition. however there is an error that total_distance is not defined when in another function called travel() it is a variable set to equal zero. where would the variable have to be for it to recognize it?

Comment: Without seeing the whole file it's hard to say, but what you are dealing with is variable scope. Is travel() in the same file with these procedures? If so putting total_distance=0 at the top of the file will fix it - that will make it a global variable.